# How to change the Design view

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm new to the programming, just got limited knowledge. I got a doubt, seems silly for u professionals. I have a program for Pay slip generator. It doesn't show the design on designer view. It just a empty window. Will get the payslip on runtime. Can you please help me...

```
Partial Class frmSalarySlip
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(frmSalarySlip))
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1 = New CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'CrystalReportViewer1
    '
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ActiveViewIndex = -1
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Name = "CrystalReportViewer1"
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1007, 498)
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'frmSalarySlip
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1007, 498)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.CrystalReportViewer1)
    Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
    Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.Name = "frmSalarySlip"
    Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    Me.Text = "Monthly Salary Slip"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
```